# How to post to Facebook fan page timeline?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I followed the steps from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

I get the success message that it was posted.

**The problem is only me (page admin user) can see the post.**

No one else can see the post.

I added the following permission:

> manage_pages,publish_actions,publish_pages

I am not sure what did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your App is live in the App settings:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app-id]/review-status/

Use the switch right next to the following text:

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to
>   the general public?

Comment: This tool is for myself only, should i still make it live?

Comment: If you want other people to see what is posted by the app it needs to be live

Comment: what wizkid said ;) - the only thing you do NOT need if it´s only for yourself is login review.

Comment: no, how would they be able to use it if you don´t offer them any page to login?

Comment: also, those permissions don´t work for other users without review anyway

Comment: what? why did you submit it? didn´t you say you don´t want other people to use it? what are you doing? i specifically said you don´t need to go through login review...

Comment: it is really time for you to take a very long look at the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review - read everything, including the stuff that is behind links.